# Which "for" loop should I use in Perl?

Tags: perl, for-loop

What are the arguments for using one of the `for` loops over the other to count through integers?

```
for my $i (0..$n) { ... }

for (my $i = 0; $i <= $n; $i++) { ... }
```

Comment: Note that those two examples are different - the first includes the upper limit $n, the second doesn't.

Comment: And that's exactly why I'd choose the first version :)

Answer (score 11):

In your case, there isn't any difference.

In other use cases, in a for-each loop you don't have control of or access to the iterator.

Using your example syntax:

```
for my $i (0..10)
{
   print "$i";
   $i++;
}
```

The above actually creates a `foreach` loop - it's the same as saying `foreach my $i (0..10)`. `$i` is a *value returned from the list*, not the iterator. The iterator is internal and you don't have any access to it; you can not control the flow of the loop.

The output from above will print `012345678910`.

**This:**

```
for ( my $i = 0; $i++ ; $i <= 10)
{
    print $i;
    $i++;
}
```

That is an actual `for` loop. You are controlling and outputting the iterator. It will output:
`0246810`

In addition:

When you do `for (1..$n)` you are invoking the [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) vs. doing a simple comparison at the top of the loop. Performance differences, however, would be immeasurable.

Comment: Why not? I was asking about this kind of foreach: `for my $i ( 0..@array-1 )`

Comment: That's not a `foreach` - in your example both are the same thing; for loops, and there's no difference.  The most common use of for-each is to go through an array *without* using an index - `foreach my $foo (@array)`. Either form will do the same thing if you're using an integer as an array index. Style wise the `for (...)` loop is generally used for that though.

Comment: @Brian: The purpose of using `$i` and `0..$n` was to clarify that I was asking about the special case of counting integers. Sorry if it wasn't clear. I was wondering about the advantages of the different styles, where the loops behave identically.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't being clear - in your example there is no difference, at all. They are both for loops, you're just using a slightly different syntax.

Comment: I may have been too lightly answering you question, sorry. See my edit.

Comment: @Brian - I believe `for` and `foreach` are synonyms. There is never any difference between them (other than readability).

Comment: @Ted - Actually, they aren't. `foreach` creates an internal iterator (called `shadow iterator` in `perlguts`) where `for` does not. You have no control over the iterator in `foreach`. That's what I was trying to point out, but the OP's original question doesn't demonstrate it well. I'm going to edit to make it more explicit.

Comment: @Brian => `for my $i (0 .. $#array) {...}` is very much a `foreach` loop, where the list being iterated is an integer range.  Just because the iterator is moving over a range and not an array does not make it any less of a `foreach` loop, since the two are both lists in list context.  In addition, see my answer for an illustration of the speed difference, which is not immeasurable.

Comment: @Brian => When the top level body of the `(...)` portion of a `for` loop does not contain semicolons, `for` is exactly a synonym for `foreach`.  When the `(...)` contains two semicolons then it is a C-style `for` loop.

Comment: The tokens `for` and `foreach` are completely interchangeable in Perl. They do not mean anything different from each other. The thing that determines whether it creates a FOROP or WHILEOP wholy depends on the syntactic constructs that follow either keyword. See `perly.y` for why.

Comment: @Brian - From the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops): _The foreach keyword is actually a synonym for the for keyword, so you can use foreach for readability or for for brevity._

Comment: @Eric - `foreach (my $i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i) { print "$i\n"; }` works perfectly well.

Comment: sorry, but you obviously mixed up the positions of condition and increment in the three-part for

Answer (score 6):

The difference between the two styles of `for` loops in Perl is one of both clarity and efficiency.

When you look at `for my $i (0 .. $n) {...}` you can instantly see the range being used without having to mentally parse a larger expression.

With `for (my $i = 0; $i <= $n; $i++) {...}` there is quite a bit more to look at, and more places where errors can creep in.

In addition, `foreach` over a range is faster than the equivalent C-style loop as shown by the following benchmark:

```
use Benchmark 'cmpthese';

for my $mag (map 10**$_, 1 .. 6) {
    print "\n$mag:\n";
    cmpthese -2 => {
        loop => sub {my $x = 0; for (my $i = 0; $i <= $mag; $i++) {$x += $i}},
        each => sub {my $x = 0; for my $i (0 .. $mag) {$x += $i}},
    };
}
```

which prints:

```
10:
         Rate loop each
loop 613877/s   --  -2%
each 625568/s   2%   --

100:
         Rate loop each
loop  79481/s   -- -24%
each 104758/s  32%   --

1000:
        Rate loop each
loop  8140/s   -- -27%
each 11220/s  38%   --

10000:
       Rate loop each
loop  832/s   -- -26%
each 1124/s  35%   --

100000:
       Rate loop each
loop 81.6/s   -- -26%
each  110/s  34%   --

1000000:
       Rate loop each
loop 6.90/s   -- -26%
each 9.27/s  34%   --
```

Comment: good to learn about [Benchmark - perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html) today.

Answer (score 5):

With the three-part `for` loop, you are able to `$i += 3` and such if you want from within the loop, but with the `foreach` loop, you are not.  That is the difference.

Answer (score 4):

The off-by-one error that you originally had in the C-style loop shows that the C-style loop is more error prone, and should only be used if you actually need access to the loop counter. A foreach loop makes it much more difficult to make an off-by-one error.

Comment: `for $i ( 0 .. $#array ) { ... }`

Comment: Yes, but in that case you are iterating over the index by *choice*, not because the syntax forces you to, and it is easier to think about the range of the indices that you wish to iterate over than to get the termination conditional correct.

Comment: Perl 5.14 brings us an even easier way to iterate over an array: `use 5.14.0; while (my ($i, $elem) = each @a) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the two loop examples you posted behave identically. In both cases, `$i` is lexically scoped (since you use the `my` keyword). I think the `0..$n` syntax is clearer, but (surprise!) not everyone would agree with that.

Comment: @tchrist - Not based on the original query, as far as I can see.

Comment: @tchrist - `$#array` is the last valid index for `@array`, not the array length. It would have to be `0 .. @array` or `0 .. $#array + 1` to get the last element of `@array`.

Comment: `..` is inclusive-inclusive, so `0 .. $#array` is correct to get all valid indices.  I think that this kind of range operator is broken, by the way.  See [EWD831](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html).

Comment: @Svante - D'oh. I overlooked that little detail about the range operator.